# Compare different fields on consecutive lines

Tags: bash, awk, compare

I want to compare different fields on consecutive lines as in :

```
TYPE    DATE     TOTAL
p1      xxxx      1
p2      xxxx      2
p3      xxxx      1
p3      xxxx      2
p3      xxxx      1
p4      xxxx      2
p5      xxxx      1
p5      xxxx      2
p5      xxxx      1
```

I want a script that will initially look into "Totals" for an entry that = 1 then it will look into the column type, as long as P remains the same with the entry that the 1 was encountered it needs to be outputted into a file.

Example result :

```
p1   xxxx   1
p3   xxxx   1
p3   xxxx   2
p3   xxxx   1
p5   xxxx   1
p5   xxxx   2
p5   xxxx   1
```

I tried using bash for this, but the code was SUPER SLOW, is there another way to do this?

```
temp=AAAAA
```

while read line
do
    type=${line:20:1}
    pod=${line:0:2}
    date=${line:9:5}

```
if [ "$type" != "2" ]
then
    echo $line >> outfile
fi

if [ "$POD" == "temp" ]
then
    echo line >> outfile
fi

temp=POD

done<$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '$NF==1{t=$1} $1==t' file
p1      xxxx      1
p3      xxxx      1
p3      xxxx      2
p3      xxxx      1
p5      xxxx      1
p5      xxxx      2
p5      xxxx      1
```

The above will run in the blink of an eye and will work robustly in all awks.

Saying a bash script was slow for manipulating text is like say your bike was slow for getting you the 30 miles to work. Of COURSE it was slow, it's not what it was designed to do. shell is for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools, not for manipulating text. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk - that's what you should be using. Get the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

```
#initialize
temp=AAAAA
check=0

#loop per line
while read line
do
type=${line:20:1}
pod=${line:0:2}
date=${line:9:5}

if [ "$type" != "2" ]
then
    echo "$line" >> outfile
    check=1         #if condition true then flag=1
fi

if [ "$pod" == "$temp" ]
then
    if [ $check -ne 1 ]  #if flag=1 dont print - otherwise it prints twice
    then
    echo "$line" >> outfile
    fi
fi

temp=$pod
check=0
done<$1
```

Best i ve managed so fat but so painfully slow. I think the 4 ifs per rotation do this :/

Comment: It will also corrupt your output given various input values. Shell is NOT for manipulating text - that's why it's very slow and incredibly hard to write robustly to do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{if($3==1){a=$1}if($1==a){print}}' your_file
```

Comment: Won't print lines before the `1` appears for the same `p`

Comment: Did I understand it incorrectly? The OP said "I want a script that will initially look into "Totals" for an entry that = 1"